# NullPointerException when using a classLoader for loading an ImageIcon

Tags: java, classloader, executable-jar, imageicon

Why do I get a nullPointerException when using ClassLoader

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("logo.png"));
```

*The NullPointerException is, according to Eclipse, on the same row where the imageIcon is created*

the image **is** there because the following works fine:

```
 ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("logo.png");
```

*I am using classloader because I want to include it in an executable jar.*

the project in the explorer of Eclipse. The main-function is in Gui.java

[image: screen shot of project resource view]

Comment: What is the structure of your project?

Comment: Where have you placed the logo,png image? is the class file the that cotains the code and logo.png are on same location?

Comment: Add a null check befoire this statement like   if(c1!=null) ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("logo.png"));

Comment: @DeviKiran - yes they are - proved by not using ClassLoader (se my question)

Comment: @npinti - I am not sure if I got you right - but I uploaded an image and added some text

Comment: Sometimes you need to add extra `\` seperator character, depending on where you placed the image, as per @DeviKiran's question.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
```

`cl` is `null`, because you call it from the bootstrap class loader, according to [java's api](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29) :

> **getClassLoader**
>
> `public ClassLoader getClassLoader()`
>
> Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null
>   in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader.

Since `cl` is null, that's why your code throws a `NullPointerException` when you use it.

Comment: May or may not - OP didn't tell exactly where the NPE occured. It is more likely though, that requested resource just was not found by the SystemClassloader

Comment: The OP is using `getSystemClassLoader()` and not `getClassLoader()`. Also `null` might be returned in case of `bootstrap` classloader. So, `String.class.getClassLoader()` will return `null`. `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` should not return `null`. @java Check what is the value of classloader before `cl` before creating image

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follow

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("logo.png"));
```

Comment: @java I think above solution will not work in static methods, better use non static and try .... it will work

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit dirty solution - but I tried to put the image in the bin-folder and then it works just fine!!!